# How to make scala regex findAllIn escape characters enclosed inside single quotes

Tags: regex, scala, escaping

I need to count number of arguments using regex for an i18n project like below

```
new Regex("\\{.*?\\}").findAllIn("{1},{2},{3} '{'4'}'").length
```

should return 3 instead of four. Can someone help with my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If arguments can contain only digits, replace the pattern with this one:

```
\\{\\d+\\}
```

Comment: I usually find that beyond a fairly minimal degree of backslash escaping Scala's triple-quoted string notation is quite helpful. Your answer's RE would be expressed as this triple-quoted string: `"""\{\d+\}"""`.